# Evaluate Polynomial by Brute Force using Java

Tags: java

I am working on a polynomials manipulation & evaluation program in Java. I have so far implemented the addition, subtraction and evaluation (Horner's) methods, however, I am struggling to understand why my brute force evaluation method is not working as I get an indexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, size: 2. I have a term class and a polynomial class. The term constructor takes two parameters, a coefficient and an exponent, while the polynomial class has two constructors, one which takes a name parameter and a second which takes a name parameter and an array of strings:-

```
public Term(int coefficient, int exponent) {
    this.coefficient = coefficient;
    this.exponent = exponent;
}

public Polynomial(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    polyTerms = new ArrayList<Term>();
}

public Polynomial(String name, String[] terms) {
    this.name = name;
    polyTerms = new ArrayList<Term>();
    for (int j = 0; j <terms.length; j = j + 2) {
        int expo = Integer.parseInt(terms[j]);
        int coeff = Integer.parseInt(terms[j+1]);
        insertPolyTerms(coeff, expo);
    }
}
```

And here's my brute force method:-

```
public double evaluatePolyBruteForce (double x, Polynomial polynomial) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i<= polyTerms.size(); i++) {
        result += polyTerms.get(i).getCoefficient() * (double)Math.pow(x,polyTerms.get(i).getExponent());
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's kinda late right now and I have a feeling that the issue is staring me in the face and I can't see it, I would appreciate any help in resolving this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program and seeing where execution diverges from what you expect?

Comment: `i<= polyTerms.size()` - yup, that's pretty much staring you in the face.

Comment: I have been debugging for the last few hours and tbh I lost patience...am just brain dead....

Comment: Also, your method doesn't actually do anything with the `polynomial` argument.

Comment: I pass The polynomial as an argument to the method....actually I have them in a txt file and read them into my structure....sorry but am not following you...what about the i<=polyTerms.size()???

Comment: oh gosh....the = sign!!!!!!! thank u mate!

Comment: thank u mate....I knew it was something dumb!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i<= polyTerms.size(); i++) {
```

change for

```
 for (int i = 0; i< polyTerms.size(); i++) {
```

you have <= and this will include 2, third pos of the array and this is out bounds limits